# Find a singular word that has a capital letter

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

So I'm working on a javascript server, which parses some text for me. and I am looking to take out a singular word that has a capital letter. I know that this problem can be solved with regex, although I have no idea how to do that, and was looking for some guidance and something to start with.

For example:

"I went to to go see my friend John yesterday"

would return "John" because of the capital letter, but wouldn't return "I", because it is the first word in the sentence.

Thanks a bunch

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html

Comment: You really need to ignore the first word in the string, and only fetch the *first* capitalized word? Are you only working with ASCII or Unicode, too?

Comment: What is a "word" here? Just ASCII letters? If yes, then SLePort's solution is the most appropriate. However, if you need to get "A" in "I have taken A from John", then it won't work for you.

Comment: What should be the result for "What did I do"? What about "I like PHP"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer:

```
(?!^)\b[A-Z]\w*
```

It matches any capitalized word that isn't at the beginning of the line (checked using a negative look-ahead and a word boundary).

[See it here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/ownphS/1).

But your requirements are sketchy...

> John and I are good friends.

would return `I`. Is that really what you want?

And it'll only work for the first sentence on a row. Also a line starting with a non character will fail. E.g

> -I like John, she said.
>
> "This is a quote."

[Check out this extended regex101](https://regex101.com/r/ownphS/2).

Answer (score 0):

```
"I went to to go see my friend John yesterday".replace(/\s[A-Z][a-z]+/g, ' ***')
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Answer (score 0):

A capital letter followed by at least one non white character:

```
[A-Z]\S+
```

Answer (score 0):

probably something like this, sorry if this is not what you want

```
var text = "I went to to go see my friend John yesterday";
var arr = text.split(' ');

var upperCaseText = [];

for(var i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
  if(/[A-Z]/.test(arr[i])) { 
    upperCaseText.push(arr[i]);
  }
} 

console.log(upperCaseText);
```